# How to delete non text characters, new line, tab, etc, from params of JSON string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I have JSON strings that may contain `\n`, `\t`, which I don't want to save into database. `strip_tags` helps only with simple strings. I am using `gsub(/(\\n)|(\\t)/, "")`.

I wonder if there is another Rails helper method or a better way to achieve this.

e.g

```
"[{\"type\":\"checkbox-group\",\"label\":\"\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\nFill in\\nthe Gap (Please\\nfill in the blank box with correct wor\",\"name\":\"checkbox-group-1527245153706\",\"values\":[{\"label\":\"Option 1\",\"value\":\"option-1\",\"selected\":true}]},{\"type\":\"text\",\"label\":\"\\n\\t\\t\\n\\t\\n\\t\\n\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\tWhat are the unique features of\\ne-commerce, digital markets, and\\ndigital goods? \\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\",\"className\":\"form-control\",\"name\":\"text-1527245426509\",\"subtype\":\"text\"}]"
```

Comment: can you please give me the example?

Comment: _"JSON strings that may contain \n, \t"_ – do you want to remove formatting or does its data contain these characters?

Comment: @Sunny I've added my sample params of JSON string.

Comment: @Stefan I want to remove those characters.

Comment: Where do these tabs and newlines come from in the first place?

Comment: @Stefan it comes with text copied from Ms. Office Word/PDF and paste it in [formBuilder](https://formbuilder.online/) field label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this one may help you,

`JSON.parse(string).map{ |a| a['label'] = a['label'].squish; a}`

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of [**`squish`**](https://apidock.com/rails/String/squish) or [**`squish!`**](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/String/squish%21)

```
"  Some text \n\n and a tab \t\t with new line \n\n  ".squish
#=> "Some text and a tab with new line"
```

`Squish` removes all the whitespace chars on both ends and grouping remaining whitespace chars (`\n`, `\t`, `space`) in one space

Comment: FYI `squish` is equivalent to `str.gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, ' ').strip`

Comment: @Deepak in my case, either `squish` or `squish!` do not help.